# Need help with complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> (a) Let $\mathcal C$ be the triangle with vertices at $\{0,1,i\}$ oriented counterclockwise. Calculate
>   $$\int_{\mathcal C}|z|^2\,dz.$$
>   (b) Evaluate
>   $$\int_{\mathcal C}z^3e^{-z^4}\,dz$$
>   along the path
>   $$\mathcal C=\left\{\sin t^2-i\frac{2t^2}\pi:0\le t\le\sqrt{\pi/2}\right\}.$$
>   (c) Evaluate
>   $$\oint_{|z|=\pi}\frac{\sin z}{z^2(z-\pi/2)}\,dz.$$

[image: What I have done (pt.1)]
[image: What I have done (pt.2)]

I'm not sure if I need to integrate over the $i\to0$ and $0\to1$ line segments as well.

Comment: It is more accurate to say "the value of the integral $is$ " rather than "the value of the integral $becomes$" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only integrated over the line segment $ 1 \to i$. You have to integrate over the the line segments $i→0$ and $0→1$ as well.

Then you have to add the three resulting integrals.